# How to disconnect all signals while function is running in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have been searching for tow days, but nothing that could help me.
I want to  disconnect all signals while functions are running. The main trick is the class that emits signal and the class that receives it are both different classes. I have a `QPushButton` in class that emits signals, and my custom class `Screen` which receives signals, they are both connected.

`The class that manages events (class sender)`

```
    Game::Game(QWidget *parent)
         : QGraphicsView(parent)
        {
            //.................................//some declaration
        
            //add the main screen
            Screen * screen = new Screen();
            screen->SetImageOnTheScreen();
            scene->addItem(screen);
        
            //make the lunch work
            QPushButton * GO = new QPushButton;
            GO->setText("GO!!!");
            GO->setGeometry(134,-98,134,99);
            scene->addWidget(GO);
            QObject::connect(GO, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), screen, SLOT(generate())); 
            //want to disconnect this connection while generate() doing its job
        
            //.................................//some declaration
        
        }
```

`Class receiver`

```
void Screen::SetImageOnTheScreen()
    {
        //.................................//some declaration
    }
    
    void Screen::setWinningIcon()
    {
        //.................................//some declaration
    }
    
    void Screen::generate()
    {
        line = 0;
    
        std::random_shuffle(mas, mas + 27);
    
        SetImageOnTheScreen();
    
        if(mas[0] == mas[1] || mas[0] == mas[2] || mas[1] == mas[2])
        {
            line = 1;
    
            delay();
            setWinningIcon();
    
            delay();
            SetImageOnTheScreen();
        }
    
        if(mas[3] == mas[4] || mas[3] == mas[5] || mas[4] == mas[5])
        {
            line = 2;
    
            delay();
            setWinningIcon();
    
            delay();
            SetImageOnTheScreen();
        }
    
        if(mas[6] == mas[7] || mas[6] == mas[8] || mas[7] == mas[8])
        {
            line = 3;
    
            delay();
            setWinningIcon();
    
            delay();
            SetImageOnTheScreen();
        }
    }
```

I was trying to use `disconnect`, and nothing. Was trying to use
`QObject::blockSignals()` the same story.

Please any help would be great!!

## **UPDATE**

`game.h`

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QPushButton>
#include "screen.h"

class Game : public QGraphicsView
{
private:
    QGraphicsScene * scene;
    QPushButton * GO;
    Screen * screen;

protected:
    virtual void wheelEvent (QWheelEvent * event);

public:
    Game(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Game();

};

#endif // GAME_H
```

`game.cpp`

```
#include "game.h"
#include <QGraphicsGridLayout>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPushButton>
#include "screen.h"
#include <QStyle>

Game::Game(QWidget *parent)
    : QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    scene->setSceneRect(0,0,400,200);

    screen = new Screen;
    screen->SetImageOnTheScreen();
    scene->addItem(screen);

    GO = new QPushButton;
    GO->setGeometry(0,0,100,50);
    GO->setText("GO");

    QObject::connect(GO, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), screen, SLOT(generate()));
    //when generate is processing i want to disconnect the button "GO" and the "screen"

    scene->addWidget(GO);
    setScene(scene);
    show();
}

void Game::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent * event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::Wheel)
        return;
    return;
}

Game::~Game()
{

}
```

`screen.h`

```
#ifndef SCREEN_H
#define SCREEN_H

#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>

class Screen : public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    int mas[27];
    int line;

    QGraphicsTextItem * text;

public:
    Screen(QGraphicsPixmapItem * parent = 0);
    void delay(int msecs);
    void setWinningIcon();
    void SetImageOnTheScreen();

public slots:
    void generate();
};

#endif // SCREEN_H
```

`screen.cpp`

```
#include "screen.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTime>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "game.h"

Screen::Screen(QGraphicsPixmapItem * parent)
    : QObject(), QGraphicsPixmapItem(parent)
{
    for(int i = 0, j =1; i < 27; i++, j++)
    {
        if(j == 10)
            j = 1;

        mas[i] = j;
    }

    line = 0;
    text = new QGraphicsTextItem(this);
}

void Screen::delay(int msecs)
{
    QTime dieTime= QTime::currentTime().addMSecs(msecs);
    while (QTime::currentTime() < dieTime)
        QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
}

void Screen::setWinningIcon()
{
    switch(line)
    {
    case 1:
        text->setPlainText("TEST_#2 I'm NOT allowed to press /GO/ \nfor 3 seconds but i can");
        text->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::red);
        break;
    case 2:
        text->setPlainText("TEST_#3 I'm NOT allowed to press /GO/ \nfor 3 seconds but i can");
        text->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::red);
        break;
    case 3:
        text->setPlainText("TEST_#4 I'm NOT allowed to press /GO/ \nfor 3 seconds but i can");
        text->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::red);
        break;
    }
}

void Screen::SetImageOnTheScreen()
{
    text->setPlainText("TEST_#1 I'm ALLOWED to press /GO/");
    text->setPos(0,50);
    text->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::green);
}

void Screen::generate()
{
    //In here i want to prevent to press "GO" while "generate()" is processing

    //Screen::grabMouse(); //here it is my solution

    std::random_shuffle(mas, mas + 27);

    SetImageOnTheScreen();

    if(mas[0] == mas[1] || mas[0] == mas[2] || mas[1] == mas[2])
    {
        line = 1;

        delay(500);
        setWinningIcon();

        delay(3000);
        SetImageOnTheScreen();
    }

    if(mas[3] == mas[4] || mas[3] == mas[5] || mas[4] == mas[5])
    {
        line = 2;

        delay(500);
        setWinningIcon();

        delay(3000);
        SetImageOnTheScreen();
    }

    if(mas[6] == mas[7] || mas[6] == mas[8] || mas[7] == mas[8])
    {
        line = 3;

        delay(500);
        setWinningIcon();

        delay(3000);
        SetImageOnTheScreen();
    }

    //Screen::ungrabMouse(); //here it is my solution
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "game.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Game w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: So, you're basically saying that you want to know how to disconnect signals in general or is this an issue that's specific to your custom class?

Comment: I would say both. I want you (guys) to help me to implement this disconnection in a right way. Mine dose not work at all.

Comment: So what's wrong? Do `blockSignals()` upon entering `generate()` and unblock it on leaving. What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: @Matt  just did this  `blockSignals(true) ... some code ... blockSignals(false)`  and i still can press `GO` button

Comment: The documentation for `blockSignals` method says "signals emitted by **this** object are blocked" (my emphasis). It won't block all signals globally. How would you close/exit your app then?

Comment: @ray would you please give a small example? We have class `A` and class `B` they are connected in class `C`. So how to disconnect `A` & `B` in a class `A`?

Comment: @Mikhail Won't be easier just to disable button then? `sender()->setEnabled(false);`

Comment: @Mikhail: In my example, class `A` is the `QMainWindow` and the class `B` is the `QPushButton`. You can see `A` disconnecting itself from `B` using `QObject::disconnect(ui->button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(on_button_clicked()));` What's *not* clear about that?

Comment: @ray I'm trying to use encapsulation pattern so i can't see my Button from another class.

Comment: @Mikhail: Encapsulation is a general object-oriented principle, not a design pattern. Interestingly, you say you don't want the button to be visible from another class, but you want to connect/disconnect from there? That would obviously make your other location not only aware of the objects, but *also* of the fact that they're connected, so it seems counter-productive for you.

Comment: @Mikhail: Please take a moment to see my updated post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update

I've taken the more recent code you've posted and made some changes to it.

### Summary

Let's start with your comment:

> i can't reach "GO" button from the screen.cpp unless it is global. And
>   i do not want to use any globals.

You're on the right track in trying to avoid globals. However, I don't think your `Screen` class really *needs* to know about your `GO` button. Instead, you could do what I suggested in [our discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94576/discussion-between-ray-and-mikhail), which is that, instead of `connect`ing your `GO` button directly to your `Screen`'s `generate()` slot, you should instead `connect` the button to a separate `on_button_clicked` event handler in your `Game` class that will:

1. disable or disconnect the `GO` button,
2. call your `screen`'s `generate()` method, and
3. re-enable or re-connect the button after `generate()` returns.

This would also imply that `generate()` may no longer need to be a slot, but that's up to you.

### Your Code - With My Suggested Updates

I've made the following changes:

In `game.h`, I added a slot to the `Game` class:

```
private slots:
    void on_go_clicked();
```

In `game.cpp`, I added the implementation as follows:

```
void Game::on_go_clicked()
{
    GO->setEnabled(false);  // or QObject::disconnect(....)
    screen->generate();
    GO->setEnabled(true);   // or QObject::connect(....)
}
```

And *also replaced* your constructor's `QObject::connect` call with the one below:

```
QObject::connect(GO, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(on_go_clicked()));
```

Now, you can keep your `Screen` class unaware of the existence of your `GO` button, which means less coupling and complexity, but still get to prevent the user from using your button in the meantime, which is what you want.

## Original Response

Basically, you need to use `QObject::disconnect` as follows:

```
QObject::disconnect(emitter, SIGNAL(signalName()), receiver, SLOT(slotName()));
```

You can do this in the slot after the event gets handled.

Disconnecting the signals/slots between the objects of interest is a better approach than trying to disconnect *all* signals globally for the whole application for several reasons, including unintended side-effects that may lead to bugs or other unexpected behavior.

In your particular example, you have:

```
QObject::connect(GO, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), screen, SLOT(generate()));
```

So to disconnect, you may only need to write this when you start processing:

```
QObject::disconnect(GO, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), screen, SLOT(generate()));
```

And then re-connect after you're done processing.

Or, as @Matt said in a comment, you could simply *disable* the button widget in the user interface and not mess around with the signals. If the user cannot click the button, then the signal cannot be emitted by the user.

This is probably a simpler and more reliable solution.

#### Signal-Blocking Update

If you still want to connect/disconnect *and* you're using Qt 5.3+, then you should use [`QSignalBlocker`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalblocker.html#details), which also takes care of preserving and restoring things back to their previous state. Quoting from their docs:

> ```
> {
> const QSignalBlocker blocker(someQObject);
> // no signals here
> }
> ```
>
> is thus equivalent to
>
> ```
> const bool wasBlocked = someQObject->blockSignals(true);
> // no signals here
> someQObject->blockSignals(wasBlocked);
> ```

## Working Sample Code

A short example app consisting of a window with a `QPushButton` and a `QListWidget` in a `QMainWindow` follows below.

#### mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_button_clicked()
{
    ui->listWidget->addItem(QString("Clicked"));

    // this is the important line :o
    QObject::disconnect(ui->button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(on_button_clicked()));
}
```

#### mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    // this naming convention allows Qt to
    // create connections automatically
    void on_button_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

#### mainwindow.ui

You can copy-paste the contents of the .ui file to reproduce the simple layout if needed. It's below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="button">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Click Me</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>27</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: thank you but can you show how to make it on my example?

Comment: @Mikhail: You should adapt my example to your situation. I already explained how you should use `QObject::disconnect`

Comment: @Mikhail: You seem dissatisfied. I hope you're not expecting someone to just write the code up for you without you making an effort to understand how your own code is working?

Comment: Imo this is the best answer considered the original post. If you want a better answer, please ask a better question. specifically read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Mikhail: Please consider up-voting and accepting the answer if it was the most helpful to you, as this the way to say 'thank you' around here. It benefits everyone, including yourself.

Comment: @ as you can see i voted-up all the users that did answer. but i can not accept the answer because the problem is still open.

Comment: @Mikhail: Have you tried any of the suggestions and examples that I provided? If yes, what *specifically* did not work for you? It's like aep said, "If you want a better answer, please ask a better question". I'd help if you had taken the time to provide a minimal (but working) example that would allow us to *reproduce* the issue.

Comment: @Mikhail: I meant to say "It'd", not "I'd"

Comment: @ray, Yes of course, i tried all the solutions you  had provided. And I'm thankful for your help.  What Specifically did not work, i can't reach `"GO" button` from the `screen.cpp` unless it is global. And i do not want to use any globals. Please look at my `new` answer, i have provided working example with my problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94576/discussion-between-ray-and-mikhail).

Comment: But isn't there a race condition with this ?

Comment: @jean-loup Why/Where would there be one?

Comment: @code_dredd if you click back before disconnecting the signal ...

Comment: What makes you think you'd be fast enough to do such a thing?...

Comment: @code_dredd If you understand what a race condition is, then this is one.

Comment: @jean-loup If you say so. Go ahead and propose a fix then. I want to see it now.

Comment: @jean-loup Nothing?

Comment: @code_dredd apparently if you call blockSignals(true) before and blockSignals(false) after event processing, it will not re-enter. I haven't look into the code.

Comment: @jean-loup Now you say "apparently" and that you "haven't look into the code"?... Look at my code. I'm not calling `blockSignals`. I'm enabling/disabling UI elements. How do your comments even apply? Also, there's [no indication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals) that this could lead to race conditions. In fact, the [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalblocker.html) recognize this is a common practice, saying "`QSignalBlocker` can be used wherever you would otherwise use a **pair of calls to `blockSignals()`**." Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26359323/4594973

Comment: @code_dredd I haven't look into the blockSignals code so i cannot be sure that it really avoid the race condition that is theoritically possible: Delayed event and double click. Maybe the blocksignals is purging the event queue from double clicks ? Also your original solution with disconnect, which is the one i was answering to, and the setEnabled method, both contain a rc theoritically, and I experienced it in practice as well. Now I see that you mention blockSignals, so you have my upvote!

Comment: @jean-loup *"both contain a rc theoritically"* By your reasoning, there's a "theoretical" race condition between *any* two lines of code, and I don't think I'm going there; it's getting to a silly/unreasonable level of nitpick. The docs don't show any RC warnings for the code in question, I've never had any issues with the above throughout the years, and, other than your anecdotal experience, which may've been buggy code due to something else, I have no objective reason to believe there're any real race conditions in the alternatives I provided in my answer. Still, thanks for the up-vote.

Answer (score 1):

What I use is blockSignals, which blocks the signaling object from sending signals: it does not however block the receiving object from receiving them, which may be your case.

Using blockSignals is good for when you want to set values to your Ui widgets but you don't want those widgets to then send valueChanged signals. An example of this would be if you have a bunch of widgets that independently all update some calculation- you wouldn't want each of them recalculating, just once when they are all set.

I would not use disconnect/connect here, because you can get into problems where signals are connected twice.