# How to call changeValue of QSpinBox only when user changed value

Tags: c++, slot, qtwidgets, qspinbox

This is my `QSpinBox` slot method:

```
void MainWindow::on_sbObjectSize_valueChanged(int arg1)
{
     /*do something*/;
}
```

I need to distinguish when this value was changed by user (by typing value or click on arrows) and when it was changed from the code (eg. using `ui->sbObjectSize->setValue(1)`). 
Is it possible to do this by overloading something, making own slot/signal or any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by checking the value returned from `sender()`. Let's say you have a button in your UI in your main window and clicking on the button changes the spin box value, then `sender()`'s value will be the address of the button pointer. `qDebug()` is really nice, since it will output other information available in your `QObject` through the metadata available. For instance you can give your `QObject` a name, and then `qDebug()` will output that name.

Here's a code snippet:

```
ui->pushButton->setObjectName("Button1");
connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [this] {
    ui->sbObjectSize->setValue(ui->sbObjectSize->value()+1);
});

connect(ui->sbObjectSize, QOverload<int>::of(&QSpinBox::valueChanged), [=] (int value) {
    //based on what this prints, you can write your code so that you can check
    qDebug()  << sender();
    if (sender() == nullptr) {
        qDebug() << "Value changed by via the spin box itself";
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Value changed by: " << sender();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify how in this lambda get `int` argument of `valueChanged`?

Comment: You can read more about it here: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: This topic shows the answer what to when I want to call action that will trigger signal but I don't want to trigger it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358945/qt-find-out-if-qspinbox-was-changed-by-user

Comment: @rainbow, cool. If you're gonna go this way, consider using QSignalBlocker instead, it's the RAII version of `blockSignals(true)` followed by `blockSignals(false)`. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalblocker.html